# how to forward ref of child inside of render props to container component using createRef()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `<Controller />` component which renders a bunch of elements in a render prop. Inside the render prop, I want to pass the CreatRef() refs of a bunch of elements back to their parent`<Controller />`.

```
  <Controller render={(props) => (
    <div className="ref-one">
      <div className="ref-two">
        <Stepper index={props.index} />
        <p>one</p>
        <p>two</p>
        <p>three</p>
        <h1>{props.title}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  )}
  />
```

So the refs should be accesable inside Controller. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Create the ref objects in the class where you're doing the rendering. Pass them in with ref= to the components they attach to, as usual. Then pass them to the controller with some name(s) other than ref.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `ref` prop in React it is always assigned to the component you attach it to, for example if you attach `createRef()` to the `ref` prop on the controller the reference set will be the controller component.

If you want to pass the `createRef()` deeper into the component, you need to use a different prop name e.g. `innerRef` you then can assign the `innerRef` prop to the child elements using the `ref` component e.g. `ref={props.innerRef}`

Additionally you can use the `React.forwardRef()` function component to allow you to still use ref but control what child element it is assigned to.

> https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html